# An error, undefined control sequence occured due to multine

Tags: errors, equations, amsmath, multline

I used `\begin{multine}` as well as `\end{multine}`. I have `\usepackage{amsmath}` 
but an error

> undefined control sequence

appears.

Comment: Welcome!  Please post a small working example.

Comment: Did you really write `multine` as your environment?

Comment: The environment you're probably thinking about is called `multline`, not `multine`. However, using the wrong environment name wouldn't cause an `undefined control sequence` error, but one saying `environment multine undefined`. In other words, we would need more information to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: the error message printed by tex tells you which command is undefined and exactly where it occurs in the source file, you have not shown the message with that information, nor shown your source so it is very hard to help you.